# How to find the unique sets of each element where difference is 1 in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have an array of integers. I want to find how all unique sets where the difference is 1 and separate them into unique sets.

example input: [3,4,5,8,9,11]

example output: [{3,4,5}, {8,9}, {11}]

What's the simplest way to do this with Python?

Comment: Difference between what? Between the numbers, or between the size of the set? It isn't clear from your example what this difference is.

Comment: Can the input list contain duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the begin of the chain and add all the elements of the chain in a set.

Here is the super simple code for this idea:

```
def f(arr):
    res = []
    st = set(arr)
    for num in st:
        if num - 1 not in st: #begin of chain
            temp = []
            while num in st:
                temp.append(num)
                num += 1
            res.append(temp)
    return res
    
print(f([3,4,5,8,9,11]))

Output: [[3, 4, 5], [8, 9], [11]]

Time complexity: O(n)
Space complexity: O(n)
```

I guess this is the best complexity we can achieve. (Don't mind the variable names in the code )

I'm assuming you input list contains no duplicates. If input is [3,4,5,8,9,11,8,9,10] do we want unique sets as [[3,4,5],[8,9,10,11],[8,9]]? If yes, then I leave it to you as an exercise. Hint: Use counter/dictionary instead of set above and it's easy.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Oh well. [Simplified](https://tio.run/##bY/NCoMwEITvPsUeE5oWgi3Ygk8iHgQTDNQ1rCvSp0@TtNLfOe3utzMw/sbDhGXlKYTeWLCiI5KXAqLIzFBD0@Zl5jjPhjPPFzsR4DKCwwgfjiRn83UPGnDib5rEZvSv4E3r4K7mX@C77dB5b7AX8U3@PCTvrgb9AWKJzZQC5LMZL4SJ5bXw5JCFFU2pjuqkKnVWWrdShnAH) a little.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks! Suggestion taken. I was trying to wrap my head around handling duplicates while coding. That is how removal from set got coded in first place.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected your part about duplicates had to do with it. I think their data doesn't have duplicates, otherwise they should've had some in their example and they should've specified how they shall be handled. Maybe their data is even already sorted, otherwise their example shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most efficient, but you can sort, then split on the difference. Here's a solution using numpy:

```py
example_input = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11]
output = np.split(np.sort(example_input),
                  np.where(np.diff(np.sort(example_input)) > 1)[0] + 1)
```

What this is doing is finding where the difference between elements of the sorted array is greater than one, then splitting the input on that. We add one to the element to split on the next set.

You can then map the arrays to sets if you prefer that.

```py
sets = [set(x) for x in output]
# [{3, 4, 5}, {8, 9}, {11}]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can start with the first number and keep incrementing it by 1 until the new value you get is not in the original list anymore.
2. Remove the values which were in the original list.
3. Repeat the same process for the remaining values.

This should get your started

```
import typing

def find_unique(elems: list[int]) -> set[int]:
  ... # fill in your code here

def find_all_unique(elems: list[int]) -> typing.Iterator[set[int]]:
  while (elems):
    yield find_unique(elems)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  my_list = [3,4,5,8,9,11]
  print list(find_all_unique(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the input list first, and initialize a set `s` with the first element.

Then go through the sorted list for the second to the last element, compare the number `num` with its previous number `prev_num`.

- If `num == prev_num` (if the input list contains duplicates), then we just ignore it.
- If `num == prev_num + 1`, then we add `num` to the same set `s`
- Otherwise, we know that we need to create a new set. We add the current set to the output list and create a new set.

```py
def find_unique_sets(input_list):
    output_list = []
    if not input_list:
        return output_list
    input_list.sort()
    s = {input_list[0]}
    prev_num = input_list[0]
    for i in range(1, len(input_list)):
        num = input_list[i]
        if num == prev_num:
            continue
        elif num == prev_num + 1:
            s.add(num)
        else:
            output_list.append(s)
            s = {num}
        prev_num = num
    output_list.append(s)
    return output_list

print(find_unique_sets([3,4,5,8,9,11]))
```